# In the English language, should the "d" be capitalized when writing "American Dollar"?

Tags: capitalization

When writing "American Dollar," should the *d* in *dollar* be capitalized?

Comment: The dollar isn't *that* Almighty. At least not lately.

Comment: It is more properly called the *United States dollar*.

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not have to be capitalized.  The following is much more common, and also correct:

> American dollar

There are times when capitalization is helpful, such as in [long lists](http://www.currencysystem.com/kb/13-144).  But it is never required.

Another thing to Keep in mind is That Excessive or unfounded Capitalization in normal writing tends to Look illiterate, unless it's wielded by an expert artist, or by earlier authors.  So I would recommend that you use "dollar" rather than "Dollar" in almost all cases.

As with all nouns, one significant use of "dollar" where it should be capitalized is in a header or title, e.g:

> The American Dollar Falls Below the Canadian Dollar!

Comment: Really, illiterate? I would say more 18th century.

Comment: Thanks, @Mitch, I edited my answer.  I _am_ speaking to someone in the 21st century, though, and  in normal writing from a person in the 21st century, excessive caps _do_ look illiterate.

Comment: I would say it depends from where it is done; many titles are written in [title case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles), even in the 21th century.

Comment: @kiam: Thank you, too - I should have thought of titles.  I edited.